# How to get a1notation of multiple rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a master sheet where a user selects rows to "reserve".
My code so far is:

```
var selectedRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
var mySelection = master.getSelection();
var myRange = mySelection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();

for ( var i = 0; i < myRange.length; i++) {
    var reserveData = myRange[i].getValues()
} 

var numRows = myRange.length

if (numRows = 1) //one row selected { 
      a1notation = "A" + selectedRow + ":" + "U" + selectedRow;
      headers = master.getRange(1, 1, 1, 21);
      newRange = master.getRange(a1notation);
      //copy headers
      headers.copyTo(resSheet.getRange(1, 1));
} else if (numRows >= 2) //multiple rows selected {
      a1notation = "A" + selectedRow + ":" + "U" + ( ??? );  
      }
```

I'm unsure how to get the other rows that are selected. These could all be adjacent rows or non-adjacent rows (if that matters) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***added***

```
a1notation = "A" + selectedRow + ":" + "U" + selectedRow;
newRange = master.getRange(a1notation);
newRange.copyTo(resSheet.getRange(resSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
```

Comment: `selectedRow` is undefined

Comment: @TheMaster, it's not, I just had it higher up in my code. Was trying to just show what was relevant and I missed that part :)
I added it. Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get all a1 notations:

```
const a1nots = mySelection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().map(range=>range.getA1Notation());
console.log(a1nots);
```

In addition, `myRange.length` would give the number of ranges in this selection and **not** the number of rows in each range.

#### References:

[Class Selection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection)

Comment: I will give this a try, thank you. It actually does return the number of rows selected, so I'm going with it.

Comment: @Mich only if it's non adjacent. It it's adjacent, it won't

Comment: I just tried it with a single row, and multiple rows (both adjacent and non adjacent) and it works...
Ok so the above answer does return what I need! Thank you.
However, before, I was using a1notation.copyTo( copies the row data to new sheet )
I cannot use .copyTo() with the above. Would you mind telling me how to accomplish that?

Comment: Just added the part I'm referring to as reference.

Comment: @Mich a1notation is a string. copyTo is a method of `range` class. you don't need a1notation. `range=>range.copyTo()` should work. If you need more help, consider asking a new question

Comment: You sir, are a god. Thank you!!

Comment: so you were right. I could've sworn my workaround for getNumRows() was working, but it's not. How do I make that work for non-adjacent rows?